# Easiest way to allow outside developers to integrate a few basic functions from my web app?

Tags: php, mysql, api, rest

I have a small web app written in php / mysql that stores customer information and does various things with it.

One of my users has expressed interest in integrating my app with the custom software (also web-based) that they use for setting up customer appointments.

Basically they want a system where, when they create a new customer account using their online software, that information is automatically relayed to my application, to create the customer account on my end as well.  This would save them having to enter the same information twice.

I am wondering what your suggestions are for the easiest way to approach something like this?  Do I have to create a full-blown RESTful API?  (I have never done anything like that before and am not really sure where to start with such a thing.)  Or is there a simpler way?

Any ideas or suggestions would be much appreciated.  Thanks (in advance) for your help!

Comment: It depends on how their app exports information.

Comment: @Ben - Fair enough.  At the moment I actually do not know how their application exports info, or even what it is written in.  I was hoping to get a very general sense of what (may be) involved in something like this, before I enter into discussion with them.

Answer (score 1):

In order for another application to communicate with yours, you will have to create some type of API, whether it be RESTful or not.

Personally, I recommend REST as it is fairly trivial to setup and there are [LOTS](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&sugexp=pfwl&tok=CfkmpL-HXu81RL4QxMlV-g&cp=16&gs_id=cf&xhr=t&q=php+rest+api+tutorial&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=php+rest+api+tut&aq=0&aqi=g1&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=cb785b2a153d08fa&biw=1680&bih=962) of tutorials on the internet to show you how. If you use Zend Framework, it's 10x easier as they have a REST controller you can extend and quickly build an API with.

Answer (score 0):

Something very simple, which has worked for me is to simply accept the information as a POST. The other application will send the information via POST, which you process in your php, and store it in mysql. if the data is sensitive, you can set up a cert and go over ssl.

Comment: I like the simplicity of this.  Are there any drawbacks to this method?